# create pagination to get database results

Tags: php

i want to create a pagination so here is what i tried

```
                <section class="products">
    <?php 



        $result_per_page=10;
        $get = mysqli_query($conn," SELECT * FROM products");
$number_of_results=mysqli_num_rows($get);
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {

    $page=1;
} else{
    $page=$_GET['page'];

}

 $this_page_first_result=($page-1)*$result_per_page;

$get = mysqli_query($conn," SELECT * FROM products LIMIT ".$this_page_first_result.','.$result_per_page);
$number_of_results=mysqli_num_rows($get);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($get)) {


    $name = $row['product_name'];
    $price = $row['product_price'];
    $img = $row['img'];

}


              $number_of_pages=ceil($number_of_results/$result_per_page);




    ?>


    <article>
                            <a href="showproduct.php">
<img src="adminpanel/<?php echo $img?>" alt="" style="height:13rem;width:13rem;"></a>
                            <h3><a href="showproduct.php"><?php echo $name;?></a></h3>
                            <h4><a href="showproduct.php">$<?php echo $price ?></a></h4>
                            <a href="cart.php" class="btn-add">Add to cart</a>
    </article>




                    </section>
                </div>
                <!-- / content -->
            </div>
            <?php  for ($page=1; $page <=$number_of_pages ; $page++) { 
                              echo '<a href="products.php?page='.$page.'">'.$page.'</a>';
                              } ?>
        </div>
        <!-- / container -->
    </div>
    <!-- / body -->
            </ul>
```

so here is my problem i only get 1 result from my data base no matter what i do i changed   `$result_per_page` to random numbers some time i get another result in my database and some time give me error i tried to replace the codes around but still did not work 
any one know where did i went wrong

Comment: In your `while` loop you're overwriting the values on each iteration. Also, you should probably output your HTML _inside_ that `while` loop

Comment: @kerbholz that makes sense im gonna try that to see if it works i wanted to design it in the html that is why i make it like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop you're overwriting the values on each iteration. You're also only outputting *one* article in your HTML. Place the `<article>..</article>` code *inside* your `while` loop to have it printed for every iteration.

Change your `while` loop to:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($get)) {
    $name = $row['product_name'];
    $price = $row['product_price'];
    $img = $row['img'];
?>
<article>
  <a href="showproduct.php"><img src="adminpanel/<?php echo $img?>" alt="" style="height:13rem;width:13rem;"></a>
  <h3><a href="showproduct.php"><?php echo $name;?></a></h3>
  <h4><a href="showproduct.php">$<?php echo $price ?></a></h4>
  <a href="cart.php" class="btn-add">Add to cart</a>
</article>

<?php
}
```

and remove the single `<article>...</article>` block you have right now.

Comment: thanks man that helped me  
i wanted to understand the error as well thanks for explaining it